# Unable to redirect output of crontab -l to file

Tags: bash, cron, io-redirection

I tried backing up my Crontab to file using following command: `crontab -l > backup/crontab`. But this creates only empty file into directory `backup` and no output is printed to terminal. Exit code of that command is `0`.

If I do `crontab -l` without redirection I get expected output:

```
/5 * * * * /path/to/script
...
```

Why is my command failing to write my Crontab contents to file and what should I do the make this work?

I am using Centos `7.7` and following versions of Cron packages installed:

```
crontabs-1.11-6.20121102git.el7.noarch
cronie-1.4.11-23.el7.x86_64
cronie-anacron-1.4.11-23.el7.x86_64
```

Shell I use is `GNU bash, version 4.2.46`.

EDIT:

```
[user@host ~]$ crontab -l > backup/crontab
[user@host ~]$ ll backup
total 248K
drwx------. 28 user user 4,0K 31.10. 09:30 .
drwxr-xr-x.  7 user user 4,0K  1.10. 12:58 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 user user 0    31.10. 09:30 crontab
...
```

Backup is local directory and has following Selinux policy: `staff_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0`.

EDIT2:

`crontab -l > /tmp/crontab` works and other locations were I have write access work too but when target is inside my home directory it fails. I wonder if `selinux` is causing this.

Comment: Could you do a copy-and-paste of the text in the terminal when you run the command and then do `ls -l backup/crontab`?

Comment: Is backup a mounted directory? Are there SELinux policies on it?

Comment: @Kusalananda I added the output to my post.

Comment: @muru Backup is local directory and has following Selinux policy: `staff_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0`.

Comment: Does it work when you put it elsewhere? e.g. `crontab -l > ~/my_crontab`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To faithfully redirect console output, save the output as a string, using quotes to absolutely preserve the contents, like so:

```
echo "$(crontab -l)" > backup/crontab
```

or, as per comments (which I didn't think through fast enough, apologies!)

```
printf "%s\n" "$(crontab -l)" > backup/crontab
```

This prevents the redirected output from being interpreted in any way... for example, the forward slash at the beginning of your crontab example. Note that "echo -e" will interpret escape sequences - eg. chars like \n, \r, \t etc. - so use "echo" without the switch.

On most systems the simple redirect (crontab -l > filename), as you use, should be just fine.

Comment: The way the user originally redirected the output of `crontab -l` to a file looks correct to me. The shell would not interpret any part of the output. With your code, however, the `echo` utility may well interpret the data, and, depending on how the shell is configured, do things like replacing `\t` with literal tabs etc.

Comment: With this contents of my Crontab get correctly saved to file. On other devices simple redirection works. I wonder why on this particular computer I this is needed.

Comment: @Kusalananda and Madoc: Absolutely agree, I also backup using simple crontab -l > <file> and it works just fine. Not sure why this use-case fails. Echo will only interpret "escaped" chars with -e CLI switch? (I left off -e so that "escaped" contents would not be interpreted). My assumption was that a crontab -l should not include any weird contents anyway, so echo "" should be good way to hack correct output.

Comment: [`printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) would be better anyway.

Comment: @sarlacii `printf "%s\n" "$(crontab -l)"` won't interpret anything

Comment: Yes, `printf` won't interpret anything, which means it should be _the same as_ `crontab -l >backup/crontab`. If it isn't, then the answer needs to include an explanation as to why it is not the same thing.  A forward slash in the redirected data is just a forward slash (I can't think of any other issue with that particular character).

Comment: Well, `$()` removes all trailing newline characters, `printf "%s\n"` adds exactly one. Empty lines at the end will disappear. This shouldn't change the logic of the file, still it's not necessarily "the same as `crontab -l >backup/crontab`".

Comment: Since it works on other machines: could it be specific uncommon shell settings? What is different in this machine compared to others (user shell, OS, versions of commands)?

Comment: @Fiximan I have used the redirection several servers and desktops running `Centos` and `Debian`. This device may have different `selinux` settings than others, there should be no other diffrences.

Comment: This solved my immediate problem so I accept it as answer. Though I am still curious about root cause of this issue and would like to figure out way to make simple redirection work.